# I'm getting a "Control may reach the end of non-void function" error with the gRPC library in Xcode

Tags: ios, xcode, cocoapods, grpc

I'm installing a bunch of "Control may reach the end of non-void function" errors in Xcode when I installed a library via Cocoapods that included the gRPC library as a dependency. What's going on? How can I fix it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The underlying gRPC issue is addressed in the latest gRPC release. Do a `pod update` and make sure you see:

> ```
> Installing gRPC 1.6.5 (was 1.6.0)
> Installing gRPC-Core 1.6.5 (was 1.6.0)
> Installing gRPC-ProtoRPC 1.6.5 (was 1.6.0)
> Installing gRPC-RxLibrary 1.6.5 (was 1.6.0)
> ```

Answer (score 2):

The reason this is probably happening is that the gRPC library uses some macros to return out of a function that the compiler doesn't seem to understand.

This is not a big deal, except that for some reason, when Cocoapods installed the pod that included gRPC, it set the **Mismatched return type** value to `Yes (treat as error)` instead of `Yes`.

You can fix this by opening up the **Pods** project inside of your XCWorkspace, find the various gRPC* targets within there, go to **Build settings** and search for **Mismatched return type**. If, for some reason, it's set to `Yes (treat as error)` then set the value to either `Yes` or `No` and your project should then build just fine.

[image]